# Won't boot to Unity or Cairo Dock on 13.04?

Tags: unity, boot, gnome, compiz, launcher

I've just booted up and when I log into either Cairo Dock or Unity/ubuntu neither of them launch, leaving me with just the wallpaper displayed but no desktop, so to speak. It's 13.04, and in order to use Cairo Dock properly I had to disable the Unity plug-in using Compiz, otherwise the Unity desktop always launched.
I've ran the file utilities etc. from the recovery options at startup, but to no avail.
I don't know what went wrong when the machine was booting this time, or how to fix it !!
I can launch the terminal from the keyboard - how do I re-enable Unity, start Compiz etc. from the terminal, so as I can start figuring out what has gone wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Further Info - I've launched Compiz, but when logged into CairoDock nothing happens when Unity is re-enabled. When logged into Unity/ubuntu there is no checkbox to re-activate Unity.

Answer (score 0):

go to tty1 (ctrl+alt+f1), and open a terminal from there:
DISPLAY=:0 gnome-terminal

(the display might not be :0, to get the actual value, run "ps -ef | grep X" in the tty1, you should see it (it's either :0 or :1 or :2))

then go back to the desktop (ctrl+alt+f7), and launch whatever command you need (for instance, try to launch compiz --replace& or cairo-dock&)

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that, but when I run the command for CairoDock I get this message returned: [1] 2326 Nothing else happens. My knowledge of Linux is sparse, as you can probably tell. I get a similar message with the compiz command. I'll put up a snapshot of the screen with what that returns.

Comment: Here's a pic of what the compiz command returns; http://i1062.photobucket.com/albums/t488/JP10101/IMG_20130508_021340.jpg

Comment: Nobody any suggestions ? My next step is to wipe the HDD and re-install 12.10, because I'm not sure how to fix this problem.